# Having an issues in making a dynamic ranking function for one column in context of another column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns, measure

I am facing a functionality issue in PowerBI. I will describe the situation her - I have data as follows:

[image]

Here I have to make slicer to pick top 10 or All others (for each Column A) according to column B. (i.e. In case we choose top 10 in slicer then metrix should show top 10 column B for each Column A so should work for All other option.

One approach in my mind is to make a measure that gives us dynamic ranking (I am taking dynamic ranking as there are other filters also on the page so our rankings always start with 1) for each column B in column A as shown here: (this results are shown if all is selected in the slicer.

[image]

As the table shows ranking Column B for each Column A.

Now suppose I choose region abc in region slicer then the table should be like as follows"

[image]

The ranking should be dynamic if I select some other region then ranking should also shuffle as per column B of the selected region only.

Comment: @smpa01 I have updated the question as per the Requirement. Please provide me with some solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
_max: = max(tbl[colB])    
Rank:= RANKX(ALLEXCEPT(tbl,tbl[colA]),[_max],,DESC,Dense)
```

try the above two measures

Comment: the dax you sent os for measure or column?

Comment: The above is DAX Measure

Comment: I used these tow measures:
_max: = max(tbl[colB])    
Rank:= RANKX(ALLEXCEPT(tbl,tbl[colA]),_max,,DESC,Dense)

I am getting the ranks roght too but ranks are not dynamic. If i put a slicer on the page and choose value ranks are not starting from 1. Its showing the results if we make a column for ranks i.e. ranks are fixed not dynamic.

Comment: @Amit based on the sample data you provided I gave you the answer. If there any more aspects you want to the calculation to influence, can you please provide the sample data accordingly. As per my solution if you create a slicer with colA it will give you the dynamic ranking. But it seems your requirement is more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this two ways with measures

#1

```
Rank =
VAR _1 =
    MAX ( 'Table'[colA] )
VAR _2 =
    MAX ( 'Table'[region] )
VAR _3 =
    RANKX (
        FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[colA] = _1 && 'Table'[region] = _2 ),
        CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[colB] ) ),
        ,
        DESC,
        DENSE
    )
RETURN
    _3
```

#2

```
Rank =
RANKX (
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[reg], 'Table'[colA] ),
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[colB] ) ),
    ,
    DESC,
    DENSE
)
```

[image: Solution]